# "MultipleObjectsReturned" from db on template

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

### **Updated:**

with "item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN)" i get the **Error:** Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

views.py

```
@login_required()
def anhang_view(request, id=None):
    contextoo = {}
    item = Kunden.objects.get(id=id)
    kontaktform_form = KontaktForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)
    creatorform_form = CreateANform()
    contextoo['creatorform_form'] = creatorform_form
    if Kunden.objects.filter(KN=item.KN).exists():
        item14 = Kunden.objects.get(KN=item.KN)
        editkontakto_form = InfoKontaktoForm(request.POST or None, instance=item14)
        contextoo['editkontakto_form'] = editkontakto_form
    if Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN).exists():
        item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN)
        ANform_form = ANform(request.POST or None, instance=item15)
        contextoo['ANform_form'] = ANform_form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        creatorform_form = CreateANform(request.POST)
        if creatorform_form.is_valid():
            cre = creatorform_form.save(commit=True)
            cre.save()
        return redirect('/Verwaltung/KontaktAnlegen')
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/anhang.html', contextoo)
```

ERROR:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta' Request Method:    GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/Verwaltung/Anhang/10 Django Version:  3.0.1
>   Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:  'QuerySet' object has
>   no attribute '_meta'

anhang.html

```
    .
    .
    .
{% if ANform_form %}
    {% for obj in ANform_form.instance %}
          <table class="table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <td width="11%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <b>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ obj.Thema }}
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">Username</td>
                    <td width="19%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">Password</td>
                    <td width="18%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">E-Mail</td>
                    <td width="37%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">Anhang</td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ obj.Username }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ obj.Password }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ obj.Email }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ obj.Anhang }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Löschen</button></a> </td>
                </td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

models.py

```
class Anhang(models.Model):
    KN = models.IntegerField(unique=False)
    Thema = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
    Anhang = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, unique=False)
```

forms.py

```
class ANform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Anhang
        fields = ['KN', 'Thema', 'Username', 'Password', 'Email', 'Anhang']
        required = ()
        labels = {
            'KN': 'KN',
            'Thema': 'Thema:',
            'Username': 'Username',
            'Password': 'Password',
            'Email': 'Email',
            'Anhang': 'Anhang',
        }


class CreateANform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Anhang
        fields = ['KN', 'Thema', 'Username', 'Password', 'Email', 'Anhang']
        required = ()
        labels = {
            'KN': 'KN',
            'Thema': 'Thema:',
            'Username': 'Username',
            'Password': 'Password',
            'Email': 'Email',
            'Anhang': 'Anhang',
        }

class KontaktForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_kundennummer(self):
        KN = self.cleaned_data['KN']
        if Kunden.objects.filter(KN_iexact=KN).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Diese Kundennummer ist bereits vergeben')
        return KN

    class Meta:
        model = Kunden
        fields = ['KN', 'Anrede', 'Name', 'Vorname', 'Infos']
        required = ()
        labels = {
            'KN': 'Kundennummer',
            'Anrede': 'Anrede',
            'Name': 'Name',
            'Vorname': 'Vorname',
            'Infos': 'Infos',
        }

class InfoKontaktoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_kundennummer(self):
        KN = self.cleaned_data['KN']
        if Kunden.objects.filter(KN_iexact=KN).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Diese Kundennummer ist bereits vergeben')
        return KN

    class Meta:
        model = Kunden
        fields = ['KN', 'Anrede', 'Name', 'Vorname']
        required = ()
        labels = {
            'KN': 'Kundennummer:',
            'Anrede': 'Anrede:',
            'Name': 'Name:',
            'Vorname': 'Vorname',
        }
```

how do i fix that? already tried with "get_list_or_404" & Anhang.objects.all()

Comment: Why are you giving positional argument in all()?

Comment: It should be `item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN)`

Comment: with : item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN) i get the error: 

Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `all()` function of django ORM is taking only one argument as `self`.

So, you can not pass queryset into all(). You can check here that how is working [all()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py) at line 909.

So, you have to replace your `item15` with below...

```
item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN)
```

For iterate loop in template you have to write below code...

```
{% for obj in ANform_form.instance %}
    {{ obj.Thema }}
    {{ obj.Username }}
{% endfor %}
```

I wrote simple for loop, you can write your html as per your requirements in for loop.

Comment: with : item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN) i get the error: 

Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: can you please add Anform form and its model in question?

Comment: Then you should get only one object not a list of object.

Comment: You have to use `get()` insted of `filter()`

Comment: But i need the whole list

Comment: Then you have to use for loop in the template for iterating your list.

Comment: how do i use a loop in the template for iterating my list?

Comment: Django Version: 3.0.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'Anhang' object is not iterable

Updated view.py

Comment: Then you have to use `item15 = Anhang.objects.get(KN=item.KN)`

Comment: cant i just do sth like item15 = Anhang.objects.all().filter(KN=item.KN) or sth like that ?

Comment: But `filter`will give you an queryset and it is a list, but you want only single object so you should use `get` instead of  `filter`

Comment: no i want multiple items, thats the thing but it gives me this error all the time, when there are 2 or more obj.

Comment: `ANform()` is a form and it will only allow single `instance` to pass it as argument. We can not give list of object or `queryset` to instance variable of `ANform`

Comment: and how do i display a whole db-table with KN=item.KN??

Comment: Then forget the form just add queryset into your context as `contextoo['ANform_form'] = item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN) `

Comment: And iterate `ANform_form` in template as a `{% for item in ANform_form%}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments to `.all` as it's meant to return all objects. You should replace

```
item15 = Anhang.objects.all(Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN))
```

With

```
item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN)
```

Alternatively, if there is only one item you can do

```
item15 = Anhang.objects.get(KN=item.KN)
```

Comment: with : item15 = Anhang.objects.filter(KN=item.KN) i get the error: 

Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'